# Multi-objective optimization - weigths

Tags: optimization, modeling

I am running an optimization algorithm: 100 $(x_1...x_{100})$ inputs and 3 outputs ($y_1,y_2,y_3$).

I know the true values $(Y_1,Y_2,Y_3)$ of the outputs and am looking for the value of the inputs. I am using genetic algorithms but my problem is the following:

The values of the outputs vary a lot in order of magnitude, lets say: 
$$Y_1 =10$$ $$ Y_2 = 0$$ $$ Y_3 = 50000$$

I want to make the cost functions something like: 
$$ Cost = \sum w_i(Y_i-y_i)$$

The values of each proposed solution are proportional to the real values, so the difference will also be proportional. For example, for a given proposed solution, I might have: $$y_1= 12, y_2=0.002, y_3 = 90000$$

If I just take the sum of the differences, the algorithm will optimize for $y_3$.

How can I escale them so that each output has the same importance?

Comment: A general way people standardize is by subtracting the mean and dividing by standard deviation.  $y_{new} = \frac{y - \mu_y}{\sigma_y}$